# Adapter isn't being refreshed

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a main activity with three fragments. In the first fragment is a listview. I populate it in the fragment's onCreateView method like this:

```
private ArrayList<MobileNETDistinctChatInfo> m_parts = new ArrayList<MobileNETDistinctChatInfo>();
public MobileNETDistinctChatInfoAdapter m_adapter;
public ListView list;
public String logged_user;

onCreateView(){
    LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
    list = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.chats_list)

    m_parts = db.MESSAGES_getAllDistinctChatInfo(logged_user); 

    // adapter extends the ArrayAdapter 
    m_adapter = new MobileNETDistinctChatInfoAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.chatlist_list_item, m_parts);

    list.setAdapter(m_adapter);

    return view;

}
```

I would like to refresh the listview in the onResume() method in fragment1, but I can't get it to work. I tried these two methods (If I use the first method, nothing happens. If I use the second, the app crashes, returning a NullPointerException):

```
# 1
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}

# 2
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            m_parts.clear();
            m_parts = db.MESSAGES_getAllDistinctChatInfo(logged_user);

            ListView list = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.chats_list);
            MobileNETDistinctChatInfoAdapter caa = (MobileNETDistinctChatInfoAdapter) list.getAdapter();
            caa.clear();

            for(MobileNETDistinctChatInfo el : m_parts){
                caa.add(el);
            }

            list.setAdapter(caa);
        }
    }
}
```

I've printed the size of m_parts and m_adapter in OnResume() and **it seems the adapter isn't being refreshed**, but m_parts is. Does anybody know why, or how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are running a `m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in a separate thread which leads the execution  of refreshing the list before even the list is modified or updated actually.

**if you debeg your code then you can see that it is working fine because the thread got enough time to get executed.**

Comment: I've also tried m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() without the runOnUiThread method and the result is the same.